# Reduce execution time when parsing files

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, parsing

I need to write a script in python2.7 which parse 4 files. 
I need to be fast as possible.
For the moment i create a loop, and i parse the 4 files one after another.
I need to understand one thing. If a created 4 parsing script programs (one for each file) and launch the 4 script in 4 different terminal, is this going to reduce the execution time (or not) ?

Thx,

Answer (score 0):

if you ave a potato pc , Yes it will Reduce the Execution Time

i suggest yu to use multithreading on every script for up the speed

```
import threading
import time

def main():
   starttime = time.time()
   endtime = time.time()
   for x in range(1,10000): # For Print 10000 Times The Character X For Try If It Reduce Or Nop
      print x
   print "Time Speled : " + round((endtime-starttime), 2) # For Show The Time

threads = []
t = threading.Thread(target=main)
threads.append(t)
t.start()
```

and you can Try the difference with threading and without it